# Create dynamic XML tags in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I am using Groovy MarkupBuilder to create an XML file. I can do it fine when I have static tags, like this

```
def userCreationNumber = "12530";
def userCreationDate = "02/02/2020";
def userCreationAuthor = "admin";
Creation{
    Revision(userCreationNumber)
    Date(userCreationDate )
    Author(userCreationAuthor)
}
```

this creates XML like this

```
<Creation>
    <Revision>12530</Revision>
    <Date>02/02/2020</Date>
    <Author>admin</Author>
</Creation>
```

but how can I create XML with dynamic tags?

I want something like this

```
def actionArray = new ArrayList();
actionArray.add("Added");
actionArray.add("Removed");
actionArray.add("Disabled");

actionArray.each{ action ->
    action(**this is a variable**){
        Revision(userCreationNumber)
        Date(userCreationDate )
        Author(userCreationAuthor)
    }
}
```

which is same as:

```
Added{
    Revision(userCreationNumber)
    Date(userCreationDate )
    Author(userCreationAuthor)
}
Removed{
    Revision(userCreationNumber)
    Date(userCreationDate )
    Author(userCreationAuthor)
}
Disabled{
    Revision(userCreationNumber)
    Date(userCreationDate )
    Author(userCreationAuthor)
}
```

this creates XML like this

```
<Added>
    <Revision>12530</Revision>
    <Date>02/02/2020</Date>
    <Author>admin</Author>
</Added>
<Removed>
    <Revision>12530</Revision>
    <Date>02/02/2020</Date>
    <Author>admin</Author>
</Removed>
<Disabled>
    <Revision>12530</Revision>
    <Date>02/02/2020</Date>
    <Author>admin</Author>
</Disabled>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GString interpolation:

```
import groovy.xml.*

def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
def userCreationNumber = "12530"
def userCreationDate = "02/02/2020"
def userCreationAuthor = "admin"

def actionArray = [ "Added", "Removed", "Disabled" ]

xml.records() {
   actionArray.each{ action ->
      "$action"{
        Revision( userCreationNumber )
        Date( userCreationDate )
        Author( userCreationAuthor )
      }
   }
}

writer
```

outputs

```
<records>
  <Added>
    <Revision>12530</Revision>
    <Date>02/02/2020</Date>
    <Author>admin</Author>
  </Added>
  <Removed>
    <Revision>12530</Revision>
    <Date>02/02/2020</Date>
    <Author>admin</Author>
  </Removed>
  <Disabled>
    <Revision>12530</Revision>
    <Date>02/02/2020</Date>
    <Author>admin</Author>
  </Disabled>
</records>
```

Note also, that you need a root element.